# Анимация jQuery и AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, анимация

Имеется функция которая должна выводит фото на страницу при добавлении в папку

```
function AddPhoto() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'private/add_photo.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {'echoImag':FILE_LIST},
    beforeSend: function() {
        inProgress = true;
    }
    }).done(function(data){
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        FILE_LIST = JSON.stringify(data['allImages']);
        if (data['newImages'].length > 0) {
        for (i=0; i<data['newImages'].length; i++) {
                if ((data['newImages'][i] != '.') && (data['newImages'][i] != '..')) {
            html += "<img src='"+dir+data['newImages'][i]+"' alt='' class='img-thumbnail' style='display:none;'>";
                }
        }
            html = html.trim();
            $(html).prependTo(".container").fadeIn();
            //$(".container").prepend(html);
            html = '';
        }
        inProgress = false;
    });
```

Все прекрасно работает, кроме анимации. Т.е. фото появляется, потом исчезает и потом появляется с эффектом анимации. Причем неважно какую длительность я ставлю все происходит с одной скоростью (эффект анимации тоже не важен).

Как сделать правильную анимацию?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(html).prependTo(".container").fadeIn();
```

попробуйте поменять длительность анимации `.fadeIn(3000)`,где `3000` значения в мс.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, верным будет привязать анимацию появления картинки, убедившись, что она загружена. Если мы начнем анимацию до того, как картинка загрузится, мы рискуем получить непредсказуемый результат. Поэтому используйте обработчик события onLoad, чтобы анимировать загруженную картинку.

```
image = $("<img src='"+dir+data['newImages'][i]+"' alt='' class='img-thumbnail' style='display:none;'>";)

image.load(function(){
      $(this).fadeIn(2000)
})
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
function AddPhoto() {
     
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      
          image = $("<img src='" + "https://placeimg.com/200/20"+i+"/arch" + 
                   "' alt='' class='img-thumbnail' style='display:none;'>");
          image.load(function(){
              $(this).fadeIn(2000)
          })
          $(".container").prepend(image);

      }

}

AddPhoto()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```